# What are the advantages in using 2 identical capacitors?

Tags: electric-circuits, capacitance

What advantage might there be in  using two identical capacitors in  parallel connected in  series with another identical parallel pair, rather than using a single capacitor?

Comment: Would http://electronics.stackexchange.com/ be a better home for this question?

Answer (score 2):

Capacitors are sometimes connected in series to increase the working voltage range, but it is not a good design technique because variances in capacitors can cause a variance in voltage and thus exceed the voltage rating on one of the capacitors.

And if you can't achieve a value of capacitance with one capacitor, sometimes putting two larger ones in series you can get the desired value.  This might also be the reason a for the odd combination of values and topology.

If you gave us the actual circuit and some information about the application we might be able to provide some more insight.

Answer (score 0):

The resultant capacitance of capacitors in parallel is the summation of the capacitances:
$$C_{eq} = \Sigma C$$

While, the inverse of the resultant capacitance of capacitors in series is the summation of their inverses:
$$\frac{1}{C_{eq}} = \Sigma\frac{1}{C}$$

Connecting capacitors in parallel will therefore help in increasing the capacitance of the circuit.

---

If each capacitor has a capacitance of $C$, your circuit will give a resultant capacitance of:
$$\frac{1}{C_{eq}} = \frac{1}{C+C} + \frac{1}{C+C}$$
$$= \frac{2}{2C}$$
$$= \frac{1}{C}$$
$$\therefore C_{eq} = C$$

Comment: What you have explained is not what the OP asks(I think). The question(again i think) is that what difference does it make to use the series-parallel combination if it produces the same equivalent capacitence.

Comment: Well I just explained what would happen in the situation she described. Perhaps she could infer the advantages according to her needs.